# Java multidimensional list

Tags: java, collections

I am declaring a multidimensional list as follows

```
List<List<Integer>> ms = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

How can i store the following data index wise in above list using a for loop

1 2 3

3 2 1

4 5 6

eg:In multidimensional arrays we do it as

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            ms[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to create a new `List` for each group, then add each element to each group, then add this `List` to the parent (`ms`) `List`

Answer (score 2):

a list of each group, something like this

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> subArray = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        subArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            subArray.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
        array.add(subArray);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i)
    {
        subArray = array.get(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < array.size(); ++j)
        {
            System.out.print(subArray.get(j)+"  ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new `List` for each group, then add each element to each group, then add this `List` to the parent (`ms`) `List`

Something like...

```
List<List<Integer>> ms = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    List<Integer> sublist = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        sublist.add(sc.nextInt());
    }
    ms.add(sublist);
}
```

for example

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize each list individually.

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
    list.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
        list.at(i).add(scanner.nextInt());
}
```

Though, if you know it is going to be 3x3 always, I'd suggest using an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a two scanner approach that can handle a jagged grid of numbers.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = 
        "1 2 3\n" +
        "3 2 1 5 7\n" +
        "4 5 6\n" +
        "5 4 3 2";

    List<List<Integer>> ms = new ArrayList();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(data);
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        ms.add(new ArrayList());
        Scanner lineInput = new Scanner(input.nextLine());
        while (lineInput.hasNext()) {
            ms.get(ms.size() - 1).add(lineInput.nextInt());
        }
    }

    System.out.println(ms);
}
```

Results:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1, 5, 7], [4, 5, 6], [5, 4, 3, 2]]
```