# Accessing elements of multi-dimensional Lists in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, nested-lists

There was this problem on HackerRank **Day 11: 2D Arrays**[1](Read the problem statement here) in which can be solved easily using arrays. But they have used 2D lists to store the data. But i could'nt figure out anyways to access contents of multi-dimensional lists by refering their index.

This is the code given to solve:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        List<List<Integer>> arr = new ArrayList<>();

        IntStream.range(0, 6).forEach(i -> {
            try {
                arr.add(
                    Stream.of(bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" "))
                        .map(Integer::parseInt)
                        .collect(toList())
                );
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        });

        bufferedReader.close();
    }
}
```

What are the possible solutions for this problem using Lists.

I tried by using toArray() method and get() method in various ways but failed. Any help would be appreciated.
[1]: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-2d-arrays/problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java multidimensional list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31151248/java-multidimensional-list)

Comment: No thats not what I meant :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int maxval = -6*9;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        //System.out.print(arr.get(i).get(j) + " ");
        int sum = arr.get(i).get(j) + arr.get(i).get(j+1) + arr.get(i).get(j+2);
        sum+=arr.get(i+1).get(j+1);
        sum+=arr.get(i+2).get(j) + arr.get(i+2).get(j+1) + arr.get(i+2).get(j+2);
        if(sum > maxval)   
            maxval = sum;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(maxval);
```

Answer (score 0):

## 100% Java solution

This is one way of solving this using three loops;

- **While loop** to loop **4 * 4 times** since we got **6 * 6 2D array**, then you need to keep the counter for the possible hourglass array which is **3 * 3 2D array**
- **Nested 2 for loops** to loop and sum the elements of an hourglass array

Please note that I've included a detailed explanation in the code below!

```
        // this is to save all hourglasses arrays sum
        ArrayList<Integer> allSum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        int fromRow = 0;
        int toRow = 3;
        
        int fromColumn = 0;
        int toColumn = 3;
        
        int counter = 0;
        
        // since the array that is given is always (6 * 6 2D array), then we need to consider
        // to loop 4 * 4 times to calculate the sum for all the 3 * 3 hourglass arrays.
        while(counter < 16) {
            
            // the sum at an instant time for an hourglass
            int sum = 0;
            
            // if we reached the last column in a specific row, then:
            if (toColumn == 7) {
                
                // reset column index to start again from 0 to 2 
                fromColumn = 0;
                toColumn = 3;
                
                // move to the next row 
                fromRow += 1;
                toRow += 1;
            }
            
            // we need these values to make sure that we do not add (1, 0) and (1, 2) to the sum considering 
            // (row, column) 
            int row = 0;
            int column = 0;

            for (int i = fromRow ; i < toRow ; i++) {
                for (int j = fromColumn ; j < toColumn ; j++) {
                    
                    if (row == 1 && column == 0) { // skip the case (1, 0)
                        column++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (row == 1 && column == 2) { // skip the case (1, 2)
                        column++;
                        continue;   
                    }
                    // add the value at a certain (i, j)
                    sum += arr.get(i).get(j);     
                    column++;
                }
                column = 0;
                row++;
            }
            allSum.add(sum);
            
            // move to a new column
            fromColumn += 1;
            toColumn += 1;
            
            counter++;
        }
        
        // print the max sum in allSum
        System.out.println(Collections.max(allSum));
```